# successfully import the OpenCV, but can't get it work

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to python. Just trying to get the basic idea of python.
Here is how I try and get error msg, after I installed the package.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')

print(img.shape)
```

but i just get a 'NoneType' msg.

It seems I successfully import the `openCV` package, but I just can't use its functions.

I did move the 'lena.jpg' to the same directory, but still get error msg.

Please advise how I can move on.

[image: error msg]

[image: lena is with us]

Comment: Are u sure the lena.jpg file is in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely that `lena.jpg` is not in your current working directory. Try specifying the exact path to your image or moving the file to the same directory as your `test.py`.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I did move the jpg to the same directory, but it seems the working directory is not at where I thought. Whne I indicate the full path. It works.

Comment: You can use ```import os``` and ```os.getcwd()``` to get your current working directory, then it should just be a matter of copying the file to the same directory.